# Simple program to compute and track grades

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, windows

I was wondering what the best language / environment to code a program that has a GUI which allows you to keep track of grades by first setting the percentages for each graded section of a class (ie. 20% homework, 25% test I-III, 5% attendance) and then being able to set your grades for each item in the sections with a given weight (ie. Homework 1 - worth 2% of hw grade received 8/10 or 80% and it would show 1.6% received of 2% total).

I have no doubt that this program already exists, but that's not my purpose for it. I want to have something to work on this summer that keeps me engaged and allows me to tailor the program to my own specifications.

In addition, I would prefer the program to be a windows application and eventually be able to transfer it to a mobile device.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're doing it to keep yourself engaged you should choose a language that you think will be most beneficial to engage yourself with.

I think I would choose Java out of convenience because it comes with a pretty good graphics library that has everything you need for this project.

However, if you want to learn about QT, a C++ graphics library, you could go with that.  It's very well-documented and comes with QT Designer to help you lay out the interface.  Takes some of the tedious programming work out of the way.  I also recommend setting up MSVC to work with QT for additional experience.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I would upvote but dont have enough rep yet